# How to download Flash videos in Internet Explorer 8?

Tags: flash, internet-explorer-8, adobe-flash

I want to download videos which I played in my Internet Explorer.

Is there any extension or add-on like Google Chrome or Mozilla Firefox has? Or any other procedure?

Comment: May I dare to ask why IE ?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few; Here's one: http://www.flashvideodownloader.org/

> Downloads flash video from video sharing websites!
>
> Flash Video Downloader helps you to download embedded flash video from YouTube-like video sharing websites with no download link available.

Also check out this other SU question, as it may help find some more: [Youtube and Google video downloaders?](https://superuser.com/questions/6675/youtube-and-google-video-downloaders)

Answer (score 0):

I've had good success using [Any Video Converter](http://www.any-video-converter.com/products/for_video_free/) to download videos from Youtube and then convert them to your desired video or audio format.